# How can I better optimize this O365 powershell script?

Tags: performance, powershell, optimization, office365

The script opens a connection to O365 and then iterates across all mailboxes looking for inbox rules that are likely to be malicious.

In our organization of 12K mailboxes, this script requires over 24 hours to run.

```
$CloudCredentials = import-clixml C:\tools\CloudCreds.xml
Write-Host "Connecting To Exchange Online..." -foregroundcolor white
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell `
                    -Credential $CloudCredentials -Authentication Basic -
AllowRedirection -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
Import-PSSession $Session -Prefix Cloud -DisableNameChecking -AllowClobber | Out-Null
Connect-MsolService -Credential $CloudCredentials
Invoke-Command -Session (Get-PSSession | ?{$_.state -eq "Opened"}) -ScriptBlock {GEt-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited | Select-Object PrimarySMTPAddress,UserPrincipalName}
foreach ($MB in $MBs) {    
    $Rules=@()
    $Rules += Get-CloudInboxRule -Mailbox $MB.UserPrincipalName -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($Rules.Length -gt 0) {
        foreach ($R in $Rules) {
            if (($R.Name -eq "postmaster") -or
                ($R.Name -eq ".net") -or
                ($R.Name -eq ".com") -or
                ($R.Name -eq ".org") -or
                ($R.Name -eq ".")
               )
           {
           write-host $MB.UserPrincipalName
           #Remove-CloudInboxRule -Mailbox $MB.UserPrincipalName -Id $R.Name -Confirm:$false
           }
        }
    }
}
```

The Get-InboxRule (here renamed to Get-CloudInboxRule) iterations seem to take the longest.  As it stands, this code requires approximately 1 hour per 1000 Mailboxes.  That means for our 15K users this requires 15 hours to scan... that's a long time when trying to look for malicious rules before spammageddon starts.

p.s this was posted in SuperUser but I realized that it's a Powershell programming issue, not really a poweruser issue.

Comment: Have you yet considered splitting the processing to multiple [background jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-5.1)?

Comment: Hi dragonspeed, the site for optimizing working solutions would be [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ,  but please avoid cross site posts.

Comment: @vonPryz - I just tried that but end up with different isues :(  
Not sure how to post up my modified version of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at Powershell Workflows for Parallel processing, i havent used this at that scale but it should speed-up a large or slow 'ForEach' loop.
I normally use this when i have to connect or ping to a large number of computers.

Example Code

```
CLS

### Worflows, Functions, etc.

#Workflow
workflow CheckMailBoxesForBadRules
{    
    #Mailboxes
    $MailBoxes = @(
        @{Name="Mailbox1"; Rules=@('rule1','rule2','rule3')}
        @{Name="Mailbox2"; Rules=@('rule1','rule2')}
        @{Name="Mailbox3"; Rules=@('rule1','rule3')}
        @{Name="Mailbox4"; Rules=@('rule2','rule3')}
        @{Name="Mailbox5"; Rules=@('rule1')}
        @{Name="Mailbox6"; Rules=@('rule2')}        
        @{Name="Mailbox7"; Rules=@('rule3')}
        @{Name="Mailbox8"; Rules=@()}
        )


    ForEach -Parallel ($Mailbox in $MailBoxes)
    {    
        $BadRules = @()
        Foreach ($Rule in $Mailbox.Rules) 
        {
            #logic
                $BadRules += $Rule
        }

        If ($BadRules){
            "$($MailBox.Name) " +
            "bad-rules: $($BadRules -join ", ")"
        }
    }
}

### Script Execution

# Workflow Start
CheckMailBoxesForBadRules
```

Output

```
Mailbox7 bad-rules: rule3
Mailbox6 bad-rules: rule2
Mailbox5 bad-rules: rule1
Mailbox4 bad-rules: rule2, rule3
Mailbox3 bad-rules: rule1, rule3
Mailbox2 bad-rules: rule1, rule2
Mailbox1 bad-rules: rule1, rule2, rule3
```

Comment: I seem to "lose" the Exchange session in the workflow, so my Get-InboxRule becomes an invalid command.

Comment: It was a quick example, workflows can look like a function but they are different, i changed the code to show you a different approach but whether you can or should use them is something you have to test out yourself.